# Can not enable mysqli extension - PHP 7.1.12, can't connect to db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have installed LAMP (everything through dnf/yum) on Fedora 27 but for some reason mysqli extension is disabled or not installed (which i doubt) When I'm trying to open phpMyAdmin i got this error:

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>
> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
>   See our documentation for more information.

I've read that mysqli should be included in php package, however there is no

> extension=php_mysqli.dll

in php.ini (simply adding this line to file doesn't work either)
How can I enable mysqli then?

Answer (score 3):

.dll files are for windows, you want .so files. You want something like this:

```
extension = mysqli.so
```

You may also have to specify the module directory:

```
extension_dir = /path/to/your/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-whatever/
```

Note, depending on your server configuration, you may also have to restart your web and/or PHP service.